# Numpy - how find unique values from a symetric similarity Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a squared symetric matrix like this:

```
[[-1.         -0.70710678 -0.70710678 -0.70710678 -0.        ]
 [-0.70710678 -1.         -1.         -1.         -0.        ]
 [-0.70710678 -1.         -1.         -1.         -0.        ]
 [-0.70710678 -1.         -1.         -1.         -0.        ]
 [-0.         -0.         -0.         -0.         -1.        ]]
```

I would like to analyze all numbers below or above the diagonal, but not the diagonal.

What can I do to find unique values from this matrix except the values in the diagonal?

Expected output : `[-0., -0.70710678]`

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is the name of the numpy array with the representation you provided, then

```
print(np.array(np.setdiff1d(a, a.diagonal())))
```

does the trick with output

```
[-0.70710678  0.        ]
```

(**Original Answer**) Alternatively,

```
import numpy as np

b = np.unique(a[~np.eye(a.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(a.shape[0],-1))
print(b)
print(np.setdiff1d(b, a.diagonal()))
```

Printing `b` will  output the unique values in the array `a` with the main diagonal elements deleted. The next line removes those numbers in the diagonal of `a` that are in `b`.

The output is

```
[-1.         -0.70710678  0.        ]
[-0.70710678  0.        ]
```

Comment: The OP don't want the diagonal values  *Expected output : `[-0., -0.70710678]`*

Comment: Yes I know. But it is fairly easy to remove those from the diagonal too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of the diagonal using `arr.diagonal()` and `np.unique` and remove them from the values of the array

```
unique = np.unique(arr)
index = np.ravel([np.where(unique == i) for i in np.unique(arr.diagonal())])
values = np.delete(unique, index)
print(values) # [-0.70710678 -0.        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python `sets`, assuming `a` the input:

```
b = np.array(list(set(a.flatten())-set(np.diagonal(a))))
```

output: `array([-0.70710678, -0.        ])`

*NB. this is faster for small arrays (the provided 25 items example) and roughly as fast as numpy operations for larger arrays (tested on 1M (1000x1000) and 100M (10k x 10k) items with 1000 unique possibilities)*

timing:

[image: perfplot timing]

code for the perfplot:

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

def guy(a):
    unique = np.unique(a)
    index = np.ravel([np.where(unique == i) for i in np.unique(a.diagonal())])
    values = np.delete(unique, index)
    return values

def mozway(a):
    return np.array(list(set(a.flatten())-set(np.diagonal(a))))

def oda(a):
    b = np.unique(a[~np.eye(a.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(a.shape[0],-1))
    return np.setdiff1d(b, a.diagonal())

def oda_setdiff(a):
    return np.array(np.setdiff1d(a, a.diagonal()))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0,1000, size=(n,n)),
    kernels=[guy, oda, oda_setdiff, mozway],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(11)],
    xlabel="array shape in each dimension",
    equality_check=None,
)
```

Comment: Nice one. Up-voted. Care to share a template of the code you use to generate that?

Comment: @oda sure, added your other solution as well ;)